# Tensorflow debugger tfdbg not starting

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to use tfdbg but it's not starting up. No error message, nothing.
Here's my code:

```
hooks = [tf_debug.LocalCLIDebugHook()]
classifier = tf.estimator.Estimator(
                model_fn=my_model,
                params)
classifier.train(input_fn= 
               lambda:dataloader.train_input_fn(current_config['batchsize']), hooks=hooks)
```

I then use

```
python -m My_TF --debug
```

The program runs as usual.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Were you able to solve it?

Comment: No, switched to a different framework instead